# P5 intersection of a vector in a PShape type Box

Tags: java, processing

I try to have a function who can detect intersection of a vector in a PShape of type Box. I create a function GetIntersection for that. It work for all box's faces execept for Front and Back faces.

```
   public PVector getIntersection(PVector rayOrigin, PVector rayDirection, PShape shape) {

        if (shape.getKind() == PShape.BOX) {
            // Get the dimensions of the box
            float x = shape.getWidth();
            float y = shape.getHeight();
            float z = shape.getDepth();

            
            PVector frontIntersection = intersect(rayOrigin, rayDirection, new PVector(-x/2, -y/2, -z/2), new PVector(x/2, -y/2, -z/2));

            PVector backIntersection = intersect(rayOrigin, rayDirection, new PVector(-x/2, -y/2, z/2), new PVector(x/2, -y/2, z/2));

            // Calculate left intersection
            PVector leftIntersection = intersect(rayOrigin, rayDirection, new PVector(-x/2, -y/2, -z/2), new PVector(-x/2, y/2, -z/2));

            // Calculate right intersection
            PVector rightIntersection = intersect(rayOrigin, rayDirection, new PVector(x/2, -y/2, -z/2), new PVector(x/2, y/2, -z/2));

            // Calculate top intersection
            PVector topIntersection = intersect(rayOrigin, rayDirection, new PVector(-x/2, y/2, -z/2), new PVector(x/2, y/2, -z/2));

            // Calculate bottom intersection
            PVector bottomIntersection = intersect(rayOrigin, rayDirection, new PVector(-x/2, -y/2, -z/2), new PVector(x/2, -y/2, z/2));


            if ( backIntersection != null && pointTouchesBox(backIntersection, shape) ) {
                test = backIntersection ;
            }


            // Check for intersections and return the closest one
            if (frontIntersection != null && pointTouchesBox(frontIntersection, shape) ) {
                println("return front\n");
                return frontIntersection;
            } else if (backIntersection != null && pointTouchesBox(backIntersection, shape) ) {
                println("return back\n");
                return backIntersection;
            } else if (leftIntersection != null && pointTouchesBox(leftIntersection, shape)  ) {
                return leftIntersection;
            } else if (rightIntersection != null && pointTouchesBox(rightIntersection, shape) ) {
                return rightIntersection;
            } else if (topIntersection != null && pointTouchesBox(topIntersection, shape) ) {
                return topIntersection;
            } else if (bottomIntersection != null && pointTouchesBox(bottomIntersection, shape) ) {
                return bottomIntersection;
            } else {
                // If no intersection was found, return null
                return null;
            }


        } else {
            // For other shape types, use the original getIntersection function
            for (int i = 0; i < shape.getChildCount(); i++) {
                PVector intersection = getIntersection(rayOrigin, rayDirection, shape.getChild(i));
                if (intersection != null) {
                    return intersection;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }




    public PVector intersect(PVector rayOrigin, PVector rayDirection, PVector p1, PVector p2) {
        PVector v1 = PVector.sub(rayOrigin, p1);
        PVector v2 = PVector.sub(p2, p1);
        PVector v3 = new PVector(-rayDirection.y, rayDirection.x, 0);
        float dot = PVector.dot(v2, v3);
        if (abs(dot) < 0.0001) {
            return null;
        }
        float t1 = cross(v2, v1).z / dot;
        float t2 = PVector.dot(v1, v3) / dot;
        if (t1 >= 0 && (t2 >= 0 && t2 <= 1)) {
            return PVector.add(rayOrigin, PVector.mult(rayDirection, t1));
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
    public static PVector cross(PVector v1, PVector v2) {
        float x = v1.y * v2.z - v1.z * v2.y;
        float y = v1.z * v2.x - v1.x * v2.z;
        float z = v1.x * v2.y - v1.y * v2.x;
        return new PVector(x, y, z);
    }
```

I know that the error is in the calculation of the variable frontIntersection and backIntersection but I didn't sucess.